# How to access Google Cloud Composer's data folder from a pod launched using KubernetesPodOperator?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a Google Cloud Composer 1 environment (Airflow 2.1.2) where I want to run an Airflow DAG that utilizes the [KubernetesPodOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html).

Cloud Composer [makes available](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket) to all DAGs a shared file directory for storing application data. The files in the directory reside in a Google Cloud Storage bucket managed by Composer. Composer uses FUSE to map the directory to the path `/home/airflow/gcs/data` on all of its Airflow worker pods.

In my DAG I run several Kubernetes pods like so:

```py
    from airflow.contrib.operators import kubernetes_pod_operator
    
    # ...

    splitter = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
        task_id='splitter',
        name='splitter',
        namespace='default',
        image='europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/redacted/splitter:2.3',
        cmds=["dotnet", "splitter.dll"],
    )
```

The application code in all the pods that I run needs to read from and write to the `/home/airflow/gcs/data` directory. But when I run the DAG my application code is unable to access the directory. Likely this is because Composer has mapped the directory into the worker pods but does not extend this courtesy to my pods.

What do I need to do to give my pods r/w access to the `/home/airflow/gcs/data` directory?

Comment: Was there any luck resolving this?

Comment: I suppose this is more or less the way to go so far https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207222572?pli=1

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Composer uses FUSE to mount certain directories from Cloud Storage into Airflow worker pods running in Kubernetes. It mounts these with default permissions that cannot be overwritten, because that metadata is not tracked by Google Cloud Storage. A possible solution is to use a bash operator that runs at the beginning of your DAG to copy files to a new directory. Another possible solution can be to use a non-Google Cloud Storage path like a `/pod` path.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for something akin to Docker's "bind mounts". Is there no equivalent concept in k8s?

Comment: Maybe Anthos[1] this unifies the management between applications and infrastructure.
[1]https://cloud.google.com/anthos

Comment: Thanks again. The volume mounted by Cloud Composer is called `gcsdir` and is of type `emptyDir`. Might it not be possible to change its type to `persistent disk` and then mount it from the pods I launch with `KubernetesPodOperator`?

Comment: Why would you want to change gcsdir from emptyDir to a persistent disk?

Anyways, you can create a GCE instance w/ volume and volumeClaim and then copy data into a pod and then connect to the volume using the [KubernetesPodOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2bafc089ce549d7afb3000129cf5a8e3b0f36fac/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py#L56).